# How to access 'this' in a java method?

Tags: jxbrowser

I have the following javascript method:

```
myFunc = function(callback) { callback.call(this, "hello", "world"); }
```

and I´m passing a java object that implements the 'call' method. In the java call method I get the two parameters "hello" and "world", but not 'this' (of course).  Is there a way to access 'this' from java?

I´m interfacing java with d3.js and d3 has lots of callbacks in this way and 'this' is where d3 stores a selection.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide code example of the Java class with the callback() method.

Comment: I´ve not managed to add code example in this comment, so I´ll add as an answer to the question bellow...

Answer (score 0):

I´m not actually coding in Java but JRuby.  In order to make a Java example
I´ll have to simplify my code bellow.  Maybe this can help some.  If not, 
I´ll try to do a Java example.

```
# Function f1 will call the callback methods cb1 and cb2 with 'this' variable
# This is just a notation for creating javascript function.  It calls 
# @browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(scrpt), whith the function
# body (everything between EOT) modified to make a valid javascript script.
# f1 is a function with 2 arguments cb1, and cb2 which should be the 
# callback functions 
f1 = B.function(<<-EOT)
  (cb1, cb2) {
      cb1.call(this, "banana", "milk");
      cb2.call(this, "arroz", "feijao");
  }
EOT

# Proc is a closure.  It receives two arguments |food1, food2|. This will
# become a java object per JRuby´s magic
proc = Proc.new { |food1, food2| puts "I hate #{food1} and #{food2}" }

# now call method f1 passing proc as the first argument and the block as 
# the second argument. So cb1 = proc and cb2 = <the block bellow>. Method
# 'send' grabs the given arguments, converts them to java objects and then
# calls jxBrowser 'invoke' method with the given arguments.
f1.send(proc) { |food1, food2| puts "eu gosto de #{food1} e #{food2}" }
```

The result of executing this code is:

```
I hate banana and milk
eu gosto de arroz e feijao
```

As can be seen, the 'this' variable is just gone... I would like to be able to
capture the 'this' variable somehow in order to be able to use the context in the blocks. I´ve managed to make a workaround that allows capturing the 'this' variable, but it requires wrapping the block in another javascript function.

The whole idea of this code is to allow a JRuby developer to write Ruby code and get this code executed in jxBrowser without needing to use any javascript.  Examples of this can already be seen by downloading mdarray-sol GEM, or going to https://github.com/rbotafogo/mdarray-sol.  There you can see multiple examples of using d3.js with JRuby.

Comment: In your code example I don't see where you register Java object with the call() method using JxBrowser JavaScript Java Bridge API: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013062-calling-java-from-javascript

Comment: I guess you didn´t understand my problem.  I did register everything fine, and the code is working. However, if I have a javascript function such as: myFunc = function(callback) { callback.call(this, 'Hello Java"); } and I do as you suggest in javascript: myFunc(window.java), then in JavaObject 'call' method I cannot read the 'this' variable.

Comment: The "this" will be converted to JSValue, so your call() java method should looks like call(JSValue theThis, String message).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you follow the instruction at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013062-calling-java-from-javascript and inject your Java object with the `call()` method correctly:

Java code:

```
browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
        Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
        JSValue window = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
        window.asObject().setProperty("java", new JavaObject());
    }
});
...
public static class JavaObject {
    public void call(JSValue window, String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
window.java.call(window, 'Hello Java!');
```